# How to make an event listener automatically load a web page on a slide show carousel?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello I have a slide show carousel and I want it set it up to automatically load a web page when it gets to the last image on the slideshow. I was thinking I should use an event listener but Im not sure how to set this up. A lot of event listeners is setup to work on click but how do i make it work when it gets to the last slide?

Im also using php code to display the images so it possible to have the event listener laod the web page when it sees  or is possible to set it up to load when it sees id="page-12"?

also Im using a 3rd party carousel that i found on youtube. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ef-jvCazifc
https://www.dropbox.com/s/z70a4q2coxcg392/amp.html?dl=0

Below is the the carousel

```
      <amp-story-page id="page-12" auto-advance-after="2s">
    <amp-story-grid-layer template="fill">
       <amp-img width="400" height="750" layout="fill" src="<?= $thumbs[10]['file'] ?>"></amp-img>
    </amp-story-grid-layer>
  </amp-story-page>
```

Comment: what kind of HTML is  `<amp-story-page` ?

Comment: Yeah i know its weird its a 3rd party carousel that I found on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ef-jvCazifc

Comment: The majority of JS events depend on user interaction. Can you specify the behavior desired? Example: Going to a website when *on* page 12? If so, how long before it happens? Or does user go to the website when leaving page 11? The former is complex whilst the latter is simple.